# Laravel 4 hostgator hosting, mkdir(): Permission denied error

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I've uploaded laravel 4 app to hostgator and have problems with mkdir() function, it doesn't allow me to create folders even native laravel classes such us File throw an error because File.php also uses mkdir() , I tryed to have parent directory 777 , however it doesn't solve the problem, still 'Permission denied', how do I solve the problem? or maybe there are other good hostings? where I'll not have this error

Answer (score 0):

You php apache user may be different try change owner to the directory to php apache user.

For laravel app directory permisssions

1. **`Directories should be 755`**
2. **`Files should be 644`**
3. **`storage & bootstrap/cache 777`**

Comment: I've changed owner of the folder to userName of my hostgator account for --      chown (__DIR__'archive' , 'myhostgatorUserName' ) it returned true , but still mkdir() doesnt work and all files are 644 and all folders 755

Comment: @MikailMika are you using a shared hosting

Comment: @MikailMika then try change your permissions through a ftp client

Comment: But what permissions should I change? permissions of the folder where I want to create a folder in?

Comment: @MikailMika you should change permissions to the folder where you aren't able to mkdir to 777. e.g if you have an images directory in public and you want to create dir programmatically then you have to give images directory 777 permission.

Comment: just tried, Unfortunatly It still throws the same error :(

Comment: @MikailMika did you recursively set 777 permissions using ftp client

Comment: yes I have tried with ftp client and with cPanel, it actually changes permissions, bacuse I can see 500 error when I set 0777 on a folder, but It is still not gaining permission, I believe I have to change the owner of that folder as well with chown() but it also doesn't work, even customer support clueless